# Segmentation Fault when compiling in Red hat but working fine with ubuntu

Tags: linux, x86, intel, nasm, redhat

Here is a code that i am executing. its giving the desired output on ubuntu with NASM 2.08 but gives a segmentation fault when compiled with Red Hat 7.3 running NASM 0.98.22
Can someone help me by telling how i can make sure it runs fine on red hat too.

```
section .data

section .text
    global _start
_start:

xor eax,eax
cdq
push eax
push long 0x68732f2f
push long 0x6e69622f
mov ebx,esp
push eax
push eax
mov ecx,esp
mov al,0xb
push eax
int 0x80
```

Comment: Is one platform 64 bit and the other platform 32 bit ? Have you tried running under a debugger (e.g. gdb) ?

Comment: yes. my ubuntu is 64 bit and the red hat is 32 bit
is that going to be a problem? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Please add the command line that you use to build the executable

Comment: $nasm -f elf test3.s 

$ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test3 test3.o

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 32 bit so when you build it you need to make sure that you build a 32 bit executable. This will happen by default on your 32 bit OS but you probably need a switch like `-m32` to achieve this on a 64 bit OS.

Comment: i am building it as 
$nasm -f elf test3.s
$ld -m elf_i386 -s -o test3 test3.o

Comment: and the red hat is a 32 bit OS
but it still gives a segmentation fault on red hat OS
but it works fine with the 64 bit ubuntu

Comment: OK - run it under gdb: `gdb test3.o` and then `run` and see which line it crashes on